# Can 'ambition' be used as a verb?

Tags: meaning, verbs, word-usage

I am proofreading a doctoral thesis that has been written by a non-native English speaker (though the English level is quite high). I've never seen "ambition" used as a verb, but I did come across an article which mentioned that historically it was used as a verb with the meaning *to campaign*.

Here is the sentence: "(The school) ambitioned to join the local elite league and excel in the education of ‘high-achievers’".

Comment: If you're a native english speaker and it sounds really awkward to you - do you really need any other reason to rephrase it? by the way, I'm not a native speaker and even so it sounds really weird to me.

Comment: Just because something sounds awkward doesn't mean it's grammatically incorrect.

Comment: language is a bit more than just grammar.

Comment: A lot of native English speakers come out with lots of stuff that sounds really awkward to me. On [the now odd] occasion, I see the need to adjust my perception of acceptability. But usage (non-count), not 'rules' (especially archaic ones) drives acceptability, and whether this usage (count) is 100% 'incorrect' or not, it sounds outlandish. Apply Orwell's Sixth.

Answer (score 3):

The OED has a **verb entry for *ambition***, but no examples more recent than 1881. It is in two main senses, the first of which is obsolete and doesn't appear to have been used since James I was on the throne!

> 1. To move to ambition, to make desirous. Obs.
>
>    a1628   F. Greville Life of Sidney (1652) Ded. sig. A4   Who..hath ambition'd me to make this offering.
> 2. To be ambitious of, to desire strongly.
>
>    a. Const. simple obj.
>
>    1664   Marquis of Worcester in H. Dircks Life 2nd Marquis Worcester (1865) xvii. 270   Whatever I have or do ambition.
>
>    1776   H. Walpole in Last Jrnls. (1859) II. 51   The Bishop of Chester had ambitioned the Bishopric of Winchester.
>
>    1823   I. D'Israeli Curiosities of Lit. 2nd Ser. I. 268   Every noble youth..ambitioned the notice of the Lady Arabella.
>
>    1881   R. Pigott in Macmillan's Mag. Dec. 174/2   The Fenian leaders ambitioned not the extinction of landlordism, but rather the reconciliation of landlords and tenants.
>
>    b. Const. inf. or clause.
>
>    1694   J. Clayton in Philos. Trans. 1693 (Royal Soc.) 17 979   Each ambitioning to engross as much as they can.
>
>    1818   T. Jefferson Writings (1830) IV. 453   Who ambitioned to be his correspondent.
>
>    1871   H. Smart Cecile 5   Ambitioning that her lover should make his mark.

Comment: Googling for "he ambitioned" gives very few hits -and they're mostly from the 19th century which ties in with this answer.

Comment: Lack of post-Victorian citations in an OED entry for a word beginning with A does not necessarily imply that a usage has fallen into desuetude.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Have you ever heard it used? I haven't. And whilst I have not been around since Queen Victoria was on the throne, I have been about for a long time!

Comment: @WS2: No, and I was not questioning the thesis that the usage is obsolete--just one of the supporting inferences.

Answer (score 2):

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ambitioned) lists it as one of the definitions of the word ambition

> verb (used with object) to seek after earnestly; aspire to.

However, neither Oxford nor Cambridge dictionaries seem to include it.

A [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ambitioned&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cambitioned%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bambitioned%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAmbitioned%3B%2Cc0) suggests that it *was* once used, but may have become archaic.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I usually don't trust Dictionary.com, especially in the context of a doctoral thesis. I neither found it in Oxford nor Merriam-Webster.